# How can I wait all 'put' actions finished in running parallel?

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-saga

```
 const data = yield all([
        // @TODO: Should be use action function.
        yield put({
            type: '@@app/PCPNAME/QUERY',
            payload: {},
        }),
        yield put({
            type: '@@app/PCPREGIONNAME/QUERY',
            payload: {},
        }),
        yield put({
            type: '@@app/PCPGROUPNAME/QUERY',
            payload: {},
        }),
        yield put({
            type: '@@app/SERVICETYPE/QUERY',
            payload: {},
        }),
        yield put({
            type: '@@app/PCPPRIMARYSPECIALTY/QUERY',
            payload: {},
        }),
    ])
console.log('DATA >>>', data)
```

When I run this function the 'DATA >>>' run before actions such as: '@@app/PCPPRIMARYSPECIALTY/QUERY', '@@app/PCPNAME/QUERY'....

How can I wait all the actions finished?

---

Updated

Example of action: `@@app/SERVICETYPE/QUERY`

```
takeLatest('@@app/SERVICETYPE/QUERY', query)
...
function* query(action: any) {
    try {
        const resData = yield call(axios.get('/myserver'))
        yield put(saveDataInStorage(resData))
    } catch (err) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your actions do not return generator functions.  The action is simply dispatched into the redux flow for other middleware, the reducers and eventually any sagas that `take` them.  The return value from `put` is simply the action.

So, as soon as the actions are dispatched, the `all` block is complete - regardless of whether any of the actions that get `take`en have completed anything.

If you want to run a bunch of other sagas in parallel and block until they're all done, you can just call the other sagas, and use `all` to call them in parallel, as per [the docs](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/ComposingSagas.html):

> Yielding to an array of nested generators will start all the sub-generators in parallel, wait for them to finish, then resume with all the results
>
> `function* mainSaga(getState) {
>         const results = yield all([call(task1), call(task2), ...])
>         yield put(showResults(results))
>       }`

```
const data = yield all([
    yield call(PCPNAME_QUERY), // where PCPNAME_QUERY is a saga
    yield call(PCPREGIONNAME_QUERY),
    yield call(PCPGROUPNAME_QUERY),
    yield call(SERVICETYPE_QUERY),
    yield call(PCPPRIMARYSPECIALTY_QUERY),
])

console.log('DATA >>>', data)
```

Comment: I'm so appreciate @Edward M Smith

Answer (score 0):

From documentation `all` effect already accepts effects. Therefore the problem in your code is `yield` before `put`.

```
 const data = yield all([
    // @TODO: Should be use action function.
    put({
        type: '@@app/PCPNAME/QUERY',
        payload: {},
    }),
    put({
        type: '@@app/PCPREGIONNAME/QUERY',
        payload: {},
    }),
    put({
        type: '@@app/PCPGROUPNAME/QUERY',
        payload: {},
    }),
    put({
        type: '@@app/SERVICETYPE/QUERY',
        payload: {},
    }),
    put({
        type: '@@app/PCPPRIMARYSPECIALTY/QUERY',
        payload: {},
    }),
])
console.log('DATA >>>', data)
```

Should work

Comment: Thanks AyJay, but it seem still not waiting all dispatch function finished. It look like 'all' function only support 'call' func

Comment: Hmmm... That is strange. I use `all` for effects in my codebase all the time.

Maybe your actions return Promise? in that case you might need to use `put.resolve`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My actions return generator function (in saga). In case it can called async func. I tried put.resolve but still not working. I updated the question above.